# Jest / async/await not working with throttling method

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

I have written a test, **always failing**, on an async "throttling" method (a method that will take another async method as argument, and will execute it as long as an exception is thrown by it, or stop when the max number of allowed retries has been reached).
**I would expect this test to succeed most of the time.**

I have this throttling method working as expected in a stand-alone script.

But when it comes to execute the same code in a test (jest), it seems that the call to throttle() is not awaited and **I cannot understand where the test output comes from (output received by jest: {})**.

When I run the test, I may change the fake execution time of `funcThatMayProcessOrThrowError` to e.g. 10s, this will have no effect on test execution time, which is always around 1.2s.

Jest is running with options  `--verbose=false --silent=false`, but I don't see any log on the console (I would expect to see frequently `...Error during the call... retrying in...`).

What am I missing to have this test **executing as expected** ?

**lib.js**

```js
const throttle = async (method, intervals, index = null) => {
  const execResult = await method()
    .catch(async error => {
      // 1. determinate the interval to apply
      if (index === null) index = 0;

      // 2. Limit throttling has been reached ?
      if (index === intervals.length) {
        throw error;
      }
    
      console.log(`[#${index}] Error during the call... retrying in ${intervals[index]}ms. (Error: ${error.message})`);
      await sleep(intervals[index]);
      return await throttle(method, intervals, index + 1);
    });
  return execResult;
};

const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
  });
};

const funcThatMayProcessOrThrowError = async (anyStringValue) => {
  await sleep(125);//simulate an execution time (ms)  
  console.log("Start processing of:", anyStringValue);
        
  //randomly raise an error
  const nb = Math.random();
  //console.log(`Random number: ${nb}`);
  if(nb > .11) { 
    //chances are about 1 in 10 to execute the function without throwing an error
    throw new Error(`An error was thrown during processing of ${anyStringValue} (nb: ${nb})`);
  }
        
  return `${anyStringValue} processed`;
};

const run = async () => {
    var intervals = [ 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
                      100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
                      100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 ]; //milliseconds
    const stringToProcess = "chandelier";
    
    const result = await throttle(async () => await funcThatMayProcessOrThrowError(stringToProcess), intervals)
        .catch(error => console.log("Error",error.message));

    console.log("--> Great !", result);
};

//launch it (works perfectly as expected)
(async () => {
    console.log("starting");
    await run();
    console.log("finishing");
})();
```

**test.js**

```
describe("throttle()", () => {

    it("should repeat execution of a function until a success, and before reaching the max number of retries", async() => {

        const stringToProcess = "chandelier";

        await expect(lib.run(stringToProcess)).toEqual(`${stringToProcess} processed`);
    });
});

/*
Test output:

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    Expected: "chandelier processed"
    Received: {}
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, took me more time to write the question than to answer it...

The test was missing `.resolves`, that is required to resolve the promise returned by the function called:

```
it("should repeat execution of a function until a success, and before reaching the max number of retries", async() => {

        const stringToProcess = "chandelier";

        await expect(lib.run(stringToProcess)).resolves.toEqual(`${stringToProcess} processed`);
    });
```

And now, the test succeeds, and shows the logs I expected.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can mark your own answer as the solution, so that it's clear that this question is resolved.

Comment: @paddotk yes but i have to wait 2 days before it's possible for me to mark it as the answer

Comment: Oh ok, I see :)